# Progress dialog not displaying

Tags: android, progressdialog

I had a progress dialog which was working before kitkat now it does not display the dialog.
If i put a debug and stop the program in post execute before the dialog dismiss it show the dialog , which woul imply that the code is working too fast to display the dialog , but this is not true it takes a good time after the dailog dismiss to show the grid view?

Another strange thing , when it did work it displayed the dialog but the circle did not turn or animate.

Any comments gratefully recieved

```
        private class LoadPhoto extends AsyncTask<String, Void, MyPhoneImagesAdapter> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // initialize the dialog
            String searchingString = getResources().getString(R.string.searchingString);
            String searchMsgString = getResources().getString(R.string.searchMsgString);
            m_dialog.setTitle("Searching...");
            m_dialog.setMessage("Please wait while loading client photos...");
            m_dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            m_dialog.setCancelable(true);
            m_dialog.show();
        }



        @Override
        protected MyPhoneImagesAdapter doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // Execution code
            // Note we can call a method in the main class but we are running it in
            // the asynchronous thread
            getPhotos();
            return getPhotos();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(MyPhoneImagesAdapter result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
// Note we can update the UI from the post execute method only note we pass the adapter which 
// we created in the do in background
            GridView grid = (GridView) getView().findViewById(R.id.photoGrid);
              grid.setAdapter(result);
               // See: ImageAdapter.java
              grid.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                          int position, long id) {
                      String tst = "Pick";
                      String sel = path+"/"+clientPhotos[position];
                      listener.onImageSelected(sel);
                      }
              });
            m_dialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Comment: where is progress dialog initialized?

Comment: Please make sure your OnPreExecute is being called, you can verify this with a toast

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing `ProgressDialog` inside the class `LoadPhoto`

Declare `ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;` in `LoadPhoto`

And use the static method of `ProgressDialog` [show()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html#show%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) as,

```
mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Searching...", "Please wait while loading client photos...", true, true);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply I have tried it out , it now shows the dialog but it will not dismiss it.

Comment: I thought there might be a dismiss(context) but no

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is because the processor does not have time to update the UI, so you have to do this manually in loop.

I'm not a android developer, but in java, back in the days i would normally use the `repaint();` function.

In c# these simple functions help to update the contorls,

```
textbox1.Invalidate();
textbox1.Update();
textbox1.Refresh();
```

I beleive java may have similar functions.